# Passing cookies from frontend to backend (separate services on GCP Cloud Run)

Tags: express, cookies, apollo-client, google-cloud-run

I am facing a rather interesting issue. I have frontend and backend services running separately on **GCP Cloud Run**. FE is **Next.js 14** + **Apollo Client** + **Supabase** for authentication. Backend is **Express** + **Apollo Server Express** + **TypeGraphQL**.

Both applications are dockarized, then deployed to Cloud Run using GitHub Actions.

I have a setup where my Apollo client in the frontend includes cookies to be sent to the backend. Then I use the cookie values to authenticate certain paths in the server. I do this by setting credentials to true when creating a new **HttpLink** instance.

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_URI,
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

And in the backend, I have the following to configure CORS.

```
const corsConfig = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://frontend-instance.a.run.app'],
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders:
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cookie',
};

app.use(cors(corsConfig));

...

const appServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema: buildSchemaSync({
  resolvers: [
    ...
  ]
});

appServer.applyMiddleware({
  cors: corsConfig,
  app,
  path: '/graphql',
});
```

This has been working as expected in localhost, however after deploying to production servers I can observe that cookies are not included in the graphql request to the backend. What could be causing this? Would this be a problem with the CORs setup, or something with Cloud Run? Given this works as expected in localhost, I'd assume the problem is not in the setup, but how Cloud Run handles passing of cookies.

Any pointer will be much appreciated.

[EDIT]

Versions:

```
NextJS:                 14.0.1
Apollo Client:          3.8.0-rc.2
Supabase:               2.38.4
Express:                4.18.2
Apollo Server Express:  3.12.0
TypeGraphQL Prisma:     0.25.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved using NextJs' rewrites rule. I edited `next.config.js` and added the following:

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api',
        destination: process.env.GRAPHQL_URI,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Then, in the code where I create an HTTP Link to backend, I simply updated the URI like so:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: BACKEND_API_PROXY_URI,
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

where `BACKEND_API_PROXY_URI` is something like `http://localhost:3000/api`

After deploying to Cloud Run, I noticed that Cookies are now being sent correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your setup:

```bash
┌─────────────────────────────────┐     ┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Frontend Service (FE)           │     │ Backend Service (BE)            │
├─────────────────────────────────┤     ├─────────────────────────────────┤
│ - Next.js 14                    │     │ - Express                       │
│ - Apollo Client + HttpLink      │     │ - Apollo Server Express         │
│ - Supabase (Auth)               │     │ - TypeGraphQL                   │
│ - Dockerized & Deployed         │     │ - Dockerized & Deployed         │
│   via GitHub Actions            │     │   via GitHub Actions            │
│   to GCP Cloud Run              │     │   to GCP Cloud Run              │
│                                 │     │                                 │
│    GraphQL Request              │     │                                 │
│    ┌──────────────────────┐     │     │                                 │
│    │ - Cookies            │──────────│                                 │
│    │ - Authentication     │     │     │                                 │
│    │   Data               │     │     │                                 │
│    └──────────────────────┘     │     │                                 │
│                                 │     │                                 │
│                                 │     │    GraphQL Response             │
│                                 │     │    ┌──────────────────────┐     │
│                                 │─────────│ - Data               │     │
│                                 │     │    │ - Session Management │     │
│                                 │     │    └──────────────────────┘     │
└─────────────────────────────────┘     └─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Assuming it is working as expected in the local environment, it should also work on [GCP Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/deploy-container). The technologies and configurations used (Next.js, Apollo Client, Express, Apollo Server Express, CORS settings, etc.) are all cloud-compatible and commonly used in cloud-based deployments.

However, the key difference between local and cloud environments often lies in domain handling, network configurations, and security policies. That can affect how cookies are handled and transmitted.

I would first make sure [cookies](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#cookie) set by the frontend are scoped to the domain and path accessible by the backend.
Cookies scoped to a specific domain or path may not be sent to a different domain.

If your production environment is HTTPS (which is [likely for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/https-request)), make sure cookies are set with `Secure` and appropriate [`SameSite` attributes](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphos/explorer/connecting-authenticating/#cookies). The `SameSite=None; Secure` attributes are often necessary for cross-site requests.

```js
document.cookie = "name=value; domain=your-domain.com; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure";
```

Use browser developer tools to inspect network traffic. Look for the `Set-Cookie` header in responses and the `Cookie` header in requests to verify if cookies are correctly set and sent.

While your CORS setup seems correct, make sure the frontend URL in production is correctly listed in the `origin` array of your CORS configuration.

Check the Cloud Run logs for any warnings or errors related to cookie handling or CORS. Sometimes, production environments have additional security measures that might interfere with cookie transmission.

If persistent issues remain with cookies, consider using authentication tokens ([like JWTs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/router/configuration/authn-jwt/)) in the `Authorization` header as a possible alternative.

---

> - I've confirmed the list of origins has the correct URL to the frontend.
> - I've updated my code to manually set an authToken cookie in the frontend with `SameSite=None; Secure` flags. Observed no change, cookies are still not passing.
> - I had already used the Authorization header method as a workaround.
>
> The problem for me with this method is since I have an SPA, and that part is done in server component, I may not be getting the most up-to-date token.
>
> I also tried returning `Same-Site` from backend preflight, this is the full list: `Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cookie, Set-Cookie`. Still no dice.

Given the additional details:

-Since the origin list is confirmed to include the correct URL, it is less likely that CORS configuration is the issue.

- Setting the `authToken` cookie with `SameSite=None; Secure` flags should have facilitated cross-origin cookie transmission, but since this did not resolve the issue, it points towards another cause.
- Using the Authorization header is a viable workaround, but the concern about not getting the most up-to-date token in an SPA context is a valid one.
- Adding `Set-Cookie` to the list of allowed headers in the backend preflight response was a good step, but since it is not working, again, the problem might not be with the CORS headers themselves.

So the issue might be in the specific deployment or networking configuration on Cloud Run, or potentially with how browsers are handling the cookies in a production environment.
It could be useful to inspect the browser's network activity in detail to see if the cookies are being set but not sent, or if they are being blocked due to security policies.
And review any specific Cloud Run settings or logs that might impact cookie handling.

---

> What if I proxy the backend query to some path on the frontend, say `/api` (using nextjs config). Lo and behold, cookies are now being sent!

That does involves a clever use of Next.js' rewrite rules to proxy GraphQL requests through the frontend service.
By directing the requests to a path on the frontend (e.g., `/api`), and *then* rewriting this path to the backend GraphQL URI, they effectively make sure the cookies, which are scoped to the frontend's domain, are included in the requests to the backend.

That approach takes advantage of the fact that cookies are sent with requests to the same origin (frontend in this case) and leverages Next.js' capability to [rewrite requests](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites) to an external API.
By proxying the requests through the frontend, that resolved the issue of cookies not being sent in the cross-origin setup, which is a common challenge in modern web development.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write this answer. A few notes here:

- I've confirmed the list of origins has the correct URL to the frontend.
- I've updated my code to manually set an `authToken` cookie in the frontend with `SameSite=None; Secure` flags. Observed no change, cookies are still not passing.
- I had already used the Authorization header method as a workaround. The problem for me with this method is since I have a SPA, and that part is done in server component, I may not be getting the most up to date token.

Comment: I also tried returning Same-Site from backend preflight, this is the full list: `Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cookie, Set-Cookie`. Still no dice.

Comment: @Grigor I have edited the answer to address your comments.

Comment: I think I figured it out. After reading your edit and confirming that I have tried all those methods, I had another idea. What if I proxy the backend query to some path on the frontend, say /api (using nextjs config). Lo and behold, cookies are now being sent! I'll answer the question with this information in case anyone else is running into a similar issue.

Comment: @Grigor Good idea! I have upvoted your answer, and I have included some comments in mine.